# touchesBegan not invoked for TextView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am unable to call touchesBegan from a text view. 
Its working fine for me in a dummy project where i have just a View and inside it a TextView.
When I try to do it in real proj , having hierarchy like: (i feel here is some problem)

```
view (parent)
 scrollview(subview)
   view (grandSubview
     textview.
```

the delegate is not getting called.
.h file

```
@interface ActionViewController : UIViewController<UITextViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *actionTakenTextView;
```

.m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    actionTakenTextView.delegate=self; //actiontakentextview is the text view i am using.
    actionTakenTextView.layer.borderWidth=1;
    actionTakenTextView.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
    // Below property is to set rounded corner of text view.
    actionTakenTextView.layer.cornerRadius=5.0;
    actionTakenTextView.clipsToBounds=YES;
}
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    NSLog(@"touchesBegan:withEvent:");
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

I feel i am missing something very small here..please help.
thanks in adv.

Comment: i tried doing back-tracking and found that scroll view is the problem here. if i remove it , it works fine.. hope it helps.

Comment: Just solved it.. i will post a complete description few hours later and will mark it as solved.

Comment: add in viewdidload UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideKeyBoard:)];
gestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
[scrollView addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];  and then define the method -(void) hideKeyBoard:(id) sender
{
   // Do whatever such as hiding the keyboard
} ..before that must set the outlet for scrollview in the .h file.

Comment: I think i cannot mark it solved..someone plz help...